# Why am i getting "ReferenceError: window is not defined" in nextjs, every time i refresh the page while Agora is imported?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, agora.io

I am getting "ReferenceError: window is not defined" in nextjs; every time i refresh the page while Agora is imported, it only happens when the Agora sdk is imported; which would suggest it has something to with it. I have tried using next/dynamic to import without ssr, but it shows "Not a function". Maybe i am not doing it well?

Here is where it is imported in(settings.js):

```js
import { createClient, createMicrophoneAudioTrack } from "agora-rtc-react";

const appId = "***";
const token = null;

export const config = { mode: "rtc", codec: "vp8", appId: appId, token: token };
export const useClient = createClient(config);
export const useMicrophoneAudioTrack = createMicrophoneAudioTrack();
export const channelName = "Main";
```

Here is where i use it(room.jsx):

```js
const client = useClient();
const { ready, track } = useMicrophoneAudioTrack();
```

It works perfectly when i just enter the page, but if i refresh it i get the "Window is not defined" error.

please can someone help? i have been stuck for quite a while now

Comment: You should create a component to encapsulate the `agora-rtc-react` logic, then dynamically load that component using `next/dynamic` with `{ ssr: false }`. Check the official Next.js example: https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/Agora-RTC-React/tree/master/example/nextjs.

Answer (score 1):

At the first rendering, window is not exist.

Please put your code in "componentDidMount" or you need to check manually:

```
const hasWindow = typeof window !== 'undefined'

if (hasWindow) {
  // your code
}
```

Comment: Still returns the same error. I also had already tried the useEffect method, was still getting the same error